# How to make use of "OR" operator for form field validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The Javascript function `FormQuote_Validator` which validates form fields should return "TRUE" and alert the message if all three input fields are submitted without any numbers else it should return "FALSE".

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form id="gform_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<div>
  <li id="field_1_25">
    <label for="input_1_25">20 Amps</label>
    <input type="number" tabindex="22" class="small" value="" step="any" id="input_1_25" name="input_25">
  </li>

  <li id="field_1_26">
    <label for="input_1_26" class="gfield_label">30 Amps</label>
    <input type="number" tabindex="23" class="small" value="" step="any" id="input_1_26" name="input_26">
  </li>

  <li id="field_1_27">
    <label for="input_1_27">40 Amps</label>
    <input type="number" tabindex="24" class="small" value="" step="any" id="input_1_27" name="input_27">
  </li>
</div>

<button onclick="FormQuote_Validator(gform_1)" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is Javascript:

```
function FormQuote_Validator(Form){
  if ((Form.input_25.value == "") || (Form.input_26.value == "") || (Form.input_27.value == "")){
    alert("Please input the size in Amps.");
    Form.input_1_25.focus();
    return (false);
  }
}
```

For some reasons `FormQuote_Validator` function returns "TRUE" even when one or two input fields are submitted with some numeric values. Is there something wrong with script code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is not working ? Any error in console ? Do elaborate _"not working!"_

Comment: Seems to work for me, see: https://jsfiddle.net/cdLyczr7/

Answer (score 0):

Because `||` means OR, that means each of the inputs will have to *not* be filled in.

I've put your code in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Haroenv/pen/LNMNjq), and I'm seeing the correct behaviour.

If you want the alert box to show up if not a single input is filled in, then you should use AND (`&&`).

Comment: This is what I need -> "each of the inputs will have to not be filled in". It should return "TRUE" only when all three input fields are submitted without any values.

Comment: No, It's not happening. Just enter any number in the first input field and hit submit. Why does it still return "TRUE"?

Comment: Then I get an alert, which is what you want.

Comment: It should return "TRUE" only when all three input fields are submitted without any values.

Comment: Then use `&&`, that means and